# Haskell: why does 'id' make this function no longer monadic?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand why adding `id` in the last line of the sequence below removes the monadic aspect:

```
Prelude> :t id
id :: a -> a
Prelude> :t Control.Monad.liftM2
Control.Monad.liftM2
  :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
Prelude> :t  (==)
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
Prelude> :t Control.Monad.liftM2 (==)
Control.Monad.liftM2 (==)
  :: (Monad m, Eq a) => m a -> m a -> m Bool
Prelude> :t Control.Monad.liftM2 (==) id
Control.Monad.liftM2 (==) id :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> Bool
Prelude>
```

How does adding `id :: a -> a` change the signature in the way it does in the last line ?

Comment: You use `id` as an argument here, as a result `m` collapses to `(->) a`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You’re fixing the type to a particular `Monad` instance, namely the “function reader” monad (`instance Monad ((->) a)`).

`id :: a -> a` and you are attempting to use it as an argument to a parameter of type `m a`, so:

```
m a  ~  a -> a
m a  ~  (->) a a
m a  ~  ((->) a) a
m    ~  (->) a
a    ~  a
```

The remainder of the signature is:

```
m a -> m Bool
```

And since `m ~ (->) a`, the resulting type is:

```
(->) a a -> (->) a Bool
(a -> a) -> (a -> Bool)
(a -> a) -> a -> Bool
```

(Plus the `Eq a` constraint from the use of `==`.)

This is useful in pointfree code, particularly using the `Applicative` instance, since you can implicitly “spread” the argument of a function to subcomputations:

```
nextThree = (,,) <$> (+ 1) <*> (+ 2) <*> (+ 3)
-- or
nextThree = liftA3 (,,) (+ 1) (+ 2) (+ 3)

nextThree 5 == (6, 7, 8)

uncurry' f = f <$> fst <*> snd
-- or
uncurry' f = liftA2 f fst snd

uncurry' (+) (1, 2) == 3
```

Comment: and there it is ! http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#v:reader . many thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `liftM2 (==)` is `(Monad m, Eq a) => m a -> m a -> m Bool`. So that means that if we call this function with `id :: b -> b` as argument, then it means that `m a` and `b -> b` are the same type.

The fact that `m ~ (->) b` holds is not a problem since `(->) r` is an instance of `Monad`, indeed in the [GHC.Base source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-822) we see:

> ```
> -- | @since 2.01
> instance Monad ((->) r) where
>     f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
> ```

This only makes sense if `m ~ (->) b`. Here the arrow `(->)` is a type constructor, and `(->) a b` is the same as `a -> b`.

So it means that if we calculate the type of `liftM2 (==) id`, we derive the following:

```
liftM2 (==)    ::  m a     -> m a -> m Bool
            id :: (b -> b)
-------------------------------------------
m ~ (->) b, a ~ b
```

This thus means that the output type of `liftM2 (==) id` is `liftM2 (==) id :: (Monad m, Eq a) => m a -> m Bool`, but we need to "specialize" this with the knowledge we obtained: that `m a` is `(->) b` and `a` is the same type as `b`, so:

```
   liftM2 (==) id :: (Monad m, Eq a) => m a -> m Bool
-> liftM2 (==) id :: (Monad m, Eq a) => (b -> a) -> (b -> Bool)
-> liftM2 (==) id :: Eq b => (b -> b) -> (b -> Bool)
-> liftM2 (==) id :: Eq b => (b -> b) -> b -> Bool
```

In short the function is still "monadic", although by using `id`, you have selected a specific monad, and thus the function is no longer applicable to all sorts of monads, only to the `(->) r` monad.